# Showing a function is discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

I've used matlab to get some idea of how the following function behaves:

$$g(\theta) = \frac{2}{\theta^3} - \frac{\pi\cos(\pi\theta)}{2\sin^3(\pi\theta)}.$$

It appears that it is discontinuous at $\theta = 0$ but I can't find a way to prove this happens. I've looked at Taylor expanding the trigonometric functions to find some solution but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : show that $g(\theta) \sim C/\theta^3$ near $0$ for a certain constant $C$. In particular, $g$ cannot be continuous near $0$ since it is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks. I should have seen that sooner.